# Pre/post increment/decrement and operator order confusion

Tags: java, operators

I was going through some exercises but I am confused in this one:

```
public static int f (int x, int y) {
  int b=y--;
  while (b>0) {
    if (x%2!=0)  {
      --x;
      y=y-2; 
    }
    else { 
      x=x/2;
      b=b-x-1; 
    }
  }
  return x+y; 
}
```

What is the purpose of `b=y--`? 
So, for example, `x=5` and `y=5` 
when we first go inside of while loop (`while (b>0)`) will `b` = 4 or 5? When I am running the code in my computer `b` is 5. And the return is 3. It is really unclear to me. Sorry if I am unclear in my question.

Comment: Read about operator precedence and pre/post increment/decrement operators.

Comment: Tracing the code in a debugger might be very helpful, as you can inspect each variable on every step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int b=y--;` first assignes `b=y` and then **decrements** `y` (`y--`).

Also take a look at the [prefix/postfix unary increment operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html).

This example (taken from the linked page) demonstrates it:

```
class PrePostDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int i = 3;
        i++;
        // prints 4
        System.out.println(i);
        ++i;               
        // prints 5
        System.out.println(i);
        // prints 6
        System.out.println(++i);
        // prints 6
        System.out.println(i++);
        // prints 7
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: decrements y by 1 after b is assigned.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between a post-increment/decrement and a pre-increment/decrement is in the [*evaluation* of the expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators).

> The pre-increment and pre-decrement operators increment (or decrement) their operand by 1, and the value of the expression is the resulting incremented (or decremented) value. In contrast, the post-increment and post-decrement operators increase (or decrease) the value of their operand by 1, but the value of the expression is the operand's original value prior to the increment (or decrement) operation.

In other words:

```
int a = 5;
int b;
b = --a;    // the value of the expression --a is a-1. b is now 4, as is a.
b = a--;    // the value of the expression a-- is a. b is still 4, but a is 3.
```

Remember that a program must evaluate expressions to do *everything*. Everything is an expression, even just a casual mention of a variable. All of the following are expressions:

- `a`
- `a-1`
- `--a && ++a`
- `System.out.println(a)`

Of course, in the evaluation of expressions, [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages) dictates the value of an expression just as the [PEMDAS](http://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-pemdas.html) you learned in grade school. Some operators, such as increment/decrement, have side effects, which is of course great fun, and one of the reasons why functional programming was created.

Answer (score 1):

I believe b would equal 5 entering the loop because

```
b=y--;
```

When the "--" is behind the variable it decrements it after the action.

Answer (score 1):

It's poor coding, as it can confuse new programmers.

The function, assuming it is passing by value, like in the example above (as opposed to passing by reference) takes a copy of `y`, decrements it, and assigns it to `b`. It does not alter the argument passed to the function when it was called.

Comment: Or perhaps it is an exercise designed to confuse new programmers to get them to really think about and understand pre and post increment/decrement operators?

Comment: +1 for its poor coding.  It is, and there is no excuse for it

Comment: @mbs probably true. Although the only lesson to take from this is; don't use prefix ever. Only use postfix on its own

Comment: I'd still argue that while it is poor production code that should not be used in a real program it has a use in pointing out the quirks or operator precedence and increment and decrement operators.

Comment: Unless it's part of a C++ class and the students are learning passing-by-references compared to passing-by-value, automatic vs static vs extern storage class modifiers, etc, the code is sloppy and inexcusable for academia and production.

Comment: I like this answer on the topic specifically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108804/modifying-arguments-passed-by-value-inside-a-function-and-using-them-as-local

Answer (score 0):

Post increment

```
x++; 
x += 1;
```

Post decrement

```
x--; 
x -=1;
```

Pre increment : `++x;`

Pre decrement : `--x;`

According to the Head First Java:

Difference between `x++` and `++x` :

```
int x = 0; int z = ++x; 
Produces: x is 1, x is 1
```

```
in x = 0; int z = x++; 
Produces: x is 1, z is 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution{
public static void main(String[] args){
int a = 10;
a = a + 1;
int b = a;`
System.out.println(b) // this will print 11.
System.out.println(b) // this will print 12.
```

// pre increment adds the previous value and add by 1. In this chase the previous value is 12, so the pre incremented value is 13.
// to be honest I don't see the difference. I think it depends on how the nature of how you use it.